# Meteor: Accounts.createUser() doesn't create user

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper, meteor-publications

i'm building an application where people Can't create their account by themselves but the first user created (me) can create users in a form in the application.

It's why I setted in /lib/config/account.js: `forbidClientAccountCreation: true,`

My problem is, I can't create users in my form when I'm logged .. (even if I set this option above with false.
Here is my code:

userAdd.js:

```
Template.userAdd.events({
'submit .new-user': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();;
    var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();;

    Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: 'toto',
        profile: {

        }
    });

    event.target.email.value = "";
    event.target.username.value = "";
}
});
```

/server/publications/user.js:

```
 Meteor.publish('users', function() {
   return Meteor.users.find();
 })

 Meteor.users.allow({
   'insert': function (userId, doc) {
     return true; 
   }
 });
```

My userList where I display the list of the users:

```
Meteor.subscribe('users');

Template.usersList.helpers({
   users: function() {
     return Meteor.users.find();
   }
});
```

I tried also with `Meteor.users.insert()` but it doesn't work too ..

Could you help me please ?

---

Added the Routes:

```
FlowRouter.route('/users', {
name: "users",
 action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('applicationLayout', {
        menu: 'menu',
        container: 'usersList'
    });
 }
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');
```

AddUser.html

```
<template name="userAdd">
  <form class="ui form new-user">
    <div class="inline fields">
        <div class="seven wide field">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="seven wide field">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <button class="ui button icon right labeled teal" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="right checkmark icon"></i>Valider</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

user.js

```
Template.tableUser.helpers({
  email: function() {
    return this.emails[0].address; 
  }
});
```

.Packages

```
insecure                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
kadira:flow-router
semantic:ui
flemay:less-autoprefixer
underscore
kadira:blaze-layout
arillo:flow-router-helpers
zimme:active-route
aldeed:collection2
accounts-password
useraccounts:flow-routing
useraccounts:semantic-ui
accounts-base
```

That's all related to the Accounts...

Comment: any errors in server terminal or browser console?

Comment: No that's the problem ... No errors on the console neither on the server. And when I type: db.users.find(); on the Meteor Mongo, I just one my first user created, not the new ones ...

Comment: what happens if you create account from `meteor shell`?

Comment: I tried with: Accounts.createUser({username: 'john', password: '12345'}) and it works but sent me the error on the console: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.Template.actionForm.helpers.email .. I didn't put an email on the meteor shell .. It's now displayed on the template table, with the good username.. So it can comes from the form do you think ?

Comment: that error is because you're trying to access `email` of a user which doesn't exist, that error is not relavant to question. Are you using `Accounts.onCreateUser()` hook or if there is any other code related to `accounts` can you post it in question

Comment: Just edited the question with code related to the users .. No hook of Accounts.onCreateUser()

Comment: I couldn't found any issue with the current code if  `forbidClientAccountCreation` is set to false

Comment: Yeah, I retried to launch the server with the forbidClientAccoutnCreation to false but it does not work ... Still no issue on the console but nothing on the collection ... :/

Comment: If you can create repo in github with reproducing error, it will be helpful to look into the issue more.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/guillaumeko/frenchys-manager thanks

Comment: You have set `forbidClientAccountCreation: true`, so you can't call `Accounts.createUser` from the client.  You will have pass everything to the server via a Meteor.method and create the account there.

Comment: Ok, I can maybe change that, but the problem is even set to false, nothing is registred ...

Comment: Also when you create an account on the client, when successful it will log you in as that new account.  This may be causing issues if you are already logged in.

Comment: I tried for a while but I couldn't fix the issue, looks like related to https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/96, only other option is sending details(password,email) to server and create account in the server side

Comment: no problem creating accounts server side with your code.  Use a Meteor.method

Comment: Thanks @JeremyK and @Sasikanth! It's working now with server side! I posted the new code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @JeremyK and @Sasikanth!
It's working now,

I changed my code to server side. Don't know if all is perfect but here is the working code:

addUser.js:

```
Meteor.subscribe('users');

Template.userAdd.events({
 'submit .new-user': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var password = $('input[name="password"]').val();
    var firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
    var lastname = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();

    Meteor.call("createUsers", email, password, firstname, lastname);

    event.target.email.value = "";
    event.target.password.value = "";
    event.target.firstname.value = "";
    event.target.lastname.value = "";
 }
});
```

/server/methods/user.js

```
Meteor.methods({
 createUsers: function(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
    Accounts.createUser({
        password: password,
        username: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
        email: email,
        createdAt: new Date(),
    });
 },

 deleteUser : function(id){
    return Meteor.users.remove(id);
 },
});
```

user.js

```
Template.tableUser.events({
  "click .delete": function () {
    var idUser= this._id;
    Meteor.call('deleteUser',{_id:idUser})
  }
});
```

Thank you very much :)